# How to install LESS on Windows (PhpStorm)?

Tags: node.js, less, phpstorm

I have a trouble with installing ***LESS Compiler*** in *PhpStorm* on *Windows*.

Firstly, I downloaded and installed ***node.js*** from official website.

After I go to the **File -> Settings -> Languages and Frameworks** and no found the Node.js menu item, where must be less installation ([documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html?origin=old_help#d329194e453)).

How to Install LESS compiler?

Comment: You have three problems. The first is your choice of OS, the second is your choice to use a CSS pre-processor, the third is your choice of IDE.

Comment: You may want to see if this helps: http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-installing-lessc-for-use-globally

Comment: @andre_m thanks) this is helpful!

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/File+Watchers+in+PhpStorm. Regarding Node.js -- you have to install Node.js support plugin manually (`Settings | Plugins`) as it is not bundled in PhpStorm by default. **P.S.** There is no need to have that plugin to use LESS files in PhpStorm. You just need node.js installed on your computer to actually run LESS compiler.

Comment: @LazyOne thanks a lot!